# No definition of [procps] for OS [osx]

Tags: ros, ros-indigo, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install ROS indigo from the website's instructions for my Mac. When I get to the section for resolving dependencies, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
opencv_apps: No definition of [procps] for OS [osx]
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224956/no-definition-of-%5Bprocps%5D-for-os-%5Bosx%5D/) by [katiewasnothere](https://answers.ros.org/users/25714/katiewasnothere/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-01-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

procps is a linux-only package, and won't install on OSX.

That said, there shouldn't be anything in ROS that depends on it. You should do two things:

- Put a file named CATKIN_IGNORE in the opencv_apps package, so that catkin doesn't try to build it. Obviously this doesn't get you a complete install, but you should be able to proceed.
- You may also need to run rosdep with the `--skip-keys=procps` option to make it ignore the bad dependency.
- File this as a bug against [opencv_apps](http://wiki.ros.org/opencv_apps) on their [issue tracker](https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/issues). Any package which is included in the default installation of ROS should work on both OSX and Linux.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-25**:
There is an existing issue for this: https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/issues/106

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-22**:
This has been fixed upstream, and the fix is released in version 1.11.11 of the opencv_apps package.